# MapKit - polylineWithCoordinates interconnects all points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mapkit

I was just curious what the correct way to draw a simple route line between a set of points was? I currently have an array of coordinates and when I pass it to polylineWithCoordinates and do all the other necessary things, it draws a big web of lines that interconnect all of the points to one another. I've looked at a few samples but none of them seem to do anything special to account for this, even when they use more than two points.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    //Add drawing of route line
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[[myCheckpoints count]];

    int i = 0;
    for (Checkpoint *ckpt in myCheckpoints)
    {
        coordinates[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([ckpt.lat floatValue] , [ckpt.lon floatValue]);
        i++;
    }

    MKPolyline *route = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: coordinates count: [myCheckpoints count]];
    [mapView addOverlay:route];

}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 5.0;

    return polylineView;

}
```

This is the code in my mapViewController that is responsible for the drawing, just in case somebody sees what I'm doing, or not doing.
[image: Here is what the result looks like]

Now that I look at everything much closer, is actually not connecting adjacent coordinates to each other. Each point only has 2 lines stemming from it connecting that point to 2 more points but I cant figure out the pattern its connecting them in.

Comment: Do any of the coordinates repeat?  Make sure the coordinates in myCheckpoints are in the order that you want the line drawn in.

Comment: Yea, all of the coordinates are unique and in the correct order. So I am right in assuming this is not supposed to be happening?

Comment: It will draw the lines in the order the coordinates are provided.  How many points are in the line?  Log the coordinates as they are added in the for-loop.

Comment: There are 20. I went ahead and logged them, none dublicated, etc. I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: Can you please post the log?  A small screenshot of the result may help also.

Comment: Added a picture as that is more helpful than the log. The log is literally just 20 pairs of floats representing lat/lon. Lon is all negative due to the points they actually represent, though that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Do any of the segments cross the Pacific Ocean?  Can you reproduce the behavior with just say 4 points?

Comment: It may turn out to be that my points are actually not in order. When taking the first 4 coordinates, its not actually the first 4 in my route. I'm going to try sorting them and seeing if that fixes the problem. No crossing of the Pacific Ocean though, but I know that breaks it as well and have found an answer here on SO that contains a fix. Will post back after sorting with results.

Comment: @Anna Karenina: You were right, I thought that I was returned my points in order, but I was wrong. I have sorted them and now my line draws correctly. If you add your suggestions from the comments into the answers section I'll go ahead and mark it right :)

Comment: how u sort coordinates(lati,long)...

Comment: @Anna same issue I have to write in Swift, is there any example for that?

Comment: @KarolyS same issue I have to write in Swift, is there any example for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the coordinates in myCheckpoints are in the order that you want the lines drawn in.

It will draw the lines in the order the coordinates are provided.

Comment: I used the block sorting method in the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: i get response from web service  i didnt get any instruction how to draw a route . i am just pass the araay of cordinates and draw a route but problem is that it draw two line one from starting to end and other  end to start point